# xsd.exe -generated file doesn't have a base type

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I was given 2 .xsd files (one includes the other at the top). Generating a class from this using xsd.exe doesn't have a base type to use (instead it has 40+ types). I expected it to have a base type to stream data into.

I misunderstood but that seems the way others implemented similar things. Reading up on Linq to XML and the XMLDocument class, the documentation doesn't seem to have what I need. Code used to generate C# class:

```
xsd.exe "c:\xml experiment\THISSCHEMA.xsd" /c /l:cs /out:"c:\xml experiment"
```

I am unable to specify a single type. How to build a data set and just stream in the correct values to get a correctly formatted XML file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do but don't you want to generate a class from both .xsd files? You can give multiple .xsds as input to the xsd.exe tool (seperated by a space). Then you can create objects of this class and you can serialize them to XML.

Comment: You need to modify the schema.  A lot of schema has option to add optional objects (children).  So you have to modify parent schema to include you optional child.

Comment: vdL I want to take an xsd generated the xml class and then give it data that it will fill in to the correct areas based on the schema.

Comment: jdweng the schema is enormous. I mean the class generated from it alone is over 15,000 lines long. My issue is that there is no base type in the class so I am unsure as to how give it the data as it requires typeOf(typehere) and there are over 100 types generated